# JasperReports rendering issue

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jasper-reports

I have a very weird `JasperReports` rendering problem.

I am using an old version of the free Java Reporting Tool [JasperReports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/): 1.3.4. It's being heavily used on a Swing finance application.

I use JasperViever class to show a preview of the report to print, and my weird problem is that the report shows perfectly fine on some computers while it erases some end-paragraph-lines in others. Paragraph is laid out on the title section and it's four or five lines length. It's being rendered from a string field value.

All computers run the **exact same** version of the application, compiled report, operating system (Windows XP) and Java Virtual Machine (1.6.0).

What is JasperReports' `JasperViewer` class using to render the report that is causing different outcomes with different computers? Different installed fonts on Windows? 
Different Video Cards?

One more thing to it: if I export the report to a PDF or HTML, the problem disappears. The resulted file I generate on every computer shows every single line of the paragraph. So I know the info is there. It's just not being rendered on **some** computers **when I user JasperViewer** class. When I print it, I get exactly what **JasperViewer** class shows on preview.

My reports are displaying loan contracts to print them and hand them to customers. So it's **extremely** important to have them complete! :-)

Comment: Exact same PDF reader on each machine?

Comment: I don't use PDF Reader. I am using JasperViewer class to render the report. When I export the report to PDF, it works fine on every single machine. :(

Comment: The viewer for iReport (which, I believe, is JasperViewer) is slightly buggy. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version, if possible, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi there. Did you ever find out what was causing this as we have the same problem, except the difference is between 2 different Ubuntu servers that the Java Swing clients are running on.